# Decimal to binary using string in c....stuck with some conceptual error

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

char bin(int);

int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    int num;
    char res[50];
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    res=bin(num);
    printf("%s",res);
    return 0;
}

char bin(int num)
{
    char str[50];
    int i,val;
    for(i=0;num>=0;i++)
    {
        val=num%2;
        str[i]=val;
        num=num/2;
    }
    return str;
}
```

I really cant understand the error in the usage of strings... to convert the decimal to binary. Whats the conceptual error Im not following?

Comment: Hi Althaf. Can you give us the error you are getting and where it happens? That will help anyone trying to answer this question.

Comment: And turn on warnings of your compiler because it would have given you warnings about the return of bin and of the assignment in main.

Comment: Note: with `res=bin(num);` you think you copy the string returned by bin. But that doesn't work in C. In C you have to use `strcpy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `str` amounts to returning a local variable, you can't do it, what you can do is to return a pointer to a previously allocated memory block that works as an array (as an alternative to the oher answer, which is a good solution).

To do this you can declare `str` as a pointer, allocate memory for it and return it, making sure the variable to which the value is assigned is also a pointer, all the rest can remain the same.

---

There are, however, problems with the `bin` function.

- Consider the statement:

```
   str[i] = val;
```

This will not work as expected you are assigning the `int` result of the operation, which will be 1 or 0, you need to convert this value to the respective character.

- The loop `for (i = 0; num >= 0; i++)` is an infinite loop because `num` will never be negative, unless you provide it a negative number in which case it will break in the first iteration, **that is to say this code only works with positive integers**. You need `>` instead of `>=`.
- Finally you need to null terminate the string when the conversion is complete.

Corrected code ([Online](https://onlinegdb.com/BJpCfXiAI)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *bin(int); //return pointer

int main() {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    int num;
    char *res; //use pointer to receive string assignment
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    res = bin(num);
    printf("%s", res);
    return 0;
}

char *bin(int num) {
    char *str = malloc(50); // allocate memory
    int i, val;

    for (i = 0; num > 0; i++) { // replacing >= with >
        val = num % 2;
        str[i] = val + '0'; // convert to character
        num = num / 2;
    }
    str[i] = '\0'; //null terminate the string
    return str;
}
```

Note that you should also check for the inputed value, if it is larger than what an `int` variable can hold it will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`char` is a single character, so `char bin(int)` will not be able to return a string (i.e. a null-terminated array of characters). And you cannot "return" an an array of characters, because C does not allow to return any array as function result. You can just pass/return pointers to the begin of such arrays.

So I'd suggest to change the interface of `bin` to reicieve the result buffer as parameter. Don't forget to "close" the string, i.e. to write the string termination character after the last "actual" character:

```
void bin(int num, char* resultBuffer) { 
   ...
   resultBuffer[i] = '\0';
}
```

In `main`, you call it then like

```
bin(num, res);
```